# For every natural number $n$: $1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots + (2n− 1) = n^2$, prove by smallest counterexample?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I am confused with the concept of "smallest counterexample". So first we have to prove base $n = 1$ so $(2-1) = 1^2$ which is true. But now what do I do?

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to prove a universal truth by a counterexample.  There shouldn't be any counterexamples.

Comment: Proof by smallest counterexample is apparently a mix of proof by induction and contradiction.  See [Proof by Smallest Counterexample](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book%3A_Book_of_Proof_(Hammack)/10%3A__Mathematical_Induction/10.03%3A_Proof_by_Smallest_Counterexample).

Comment: Ahhh, of course.  Proof by the "minimal criminal."

Answer (score 1):

Given any statement of the form "For all natural numbers $n$, [...]", if there are any counterexamples, then there is necessarily a smallest counterexample. We assume that there is a counterexample, and therefore a smallest counterexample, and call it $k$.

The goal is to reach a contradiction and this conclude that there cannot be any counterexamples, and therefore that the statement is true for all natural numbers.

There are now two possibilities. Either $k$ is the smallest possible natural number (whether that's $0$ or $1$ is a matter of definition), or it isn't. The former is easily disproven, that's the base case.

So the statement makes sense and is true for $n=k-1$. Which is to say, we have
$$
1+3+\cdots+(2k-3)=(k-1)^2
$$
What does that say about our smallest counterexample? Well, we have
$$
1+3+\cdots+(2k-3)+(2k-1)=(k-1)^2+(2k-1)\\
=k^2-2k+1+2j-1=k^2
$$
But this goes against $k$ being the smallest counterexample. So we have reached a contradiction, and finished the proof.

PS. This way of writing a proof by contradiction isn't actually necessary. We don't need the contradiction here to conclude. If we remove the initial assumption-for-contradiction, this proof simply shows directly (by way of induction) that the statement is true for all $n$. But this "smallest counterexample" way of thinking may be an approachable way to learn induction in the first place.

Comment: I thought this might have been the point of the exercise, but it seemed so unnecessary.

Comment: @Randall I have not tried it myself, but I am optimistic about this approach for _teaching_ induction. It seems like it may be less abstract for the untrained student, compared to the standard domino effect analogy.

Answer (score 0):

There not exist counterexamples indeed

$$n^2-(n-1)^2= 2n-1 \implies n^2 =(n-1)^2+(2n-1)$$

To proceed by induction, for the inductive step, just use that assuming true as hypotesis

$$1+3+5+\ldots+(2n-1)=n^2 $$

we obtain

$$ 1+3+5+\ldots+(2n-1)+(2n+1)=n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$$

---

Assume that the identity holds for $n=1$ up to a minimum value $n=k$ such that

$$1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots +(2k-3)+ (2k− 1) \neq k^2$$

but by hypotesis we have that

$$1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots +(2k-3) =(k-1)^2$$

and

$$(k-1)^2+ (2k− 1) =k^2-2k+1+2k-1= k^2$$

which is a contradiction therefore such minimum value doesn't exist and the identity is always true.